# Does a dictionary of numpy arrays really use less memory than an ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, memory-management, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to find a memory efficient way to store data in python variables for quick access and analysis. I initialize an 2d array in `numpy` and then find its memory usage (using `sys` so I can compare to other variable types later) via the following:

```py
a = np.zeros((1000,1000), dtype=np.float32)
print('The size of the numpy array is {} bytes'.format(sys.getsizeof(a)))
```

Which returns: `The size of the numpy array is 4000112 bytes`

I can move this into a dictionary of 1d `numpy` arrays using the following for-loop:

```py
b = {}
for ii in range(1000):
    b[f'{ii}']=a[:,ii]

print('The size of the dictionary is {} bytes'.format(sys.getsizeof(b)))
```

Which returns: `The size of the dictionary is 36968 bytes`. The dictionary size persists even if I delete `a` and run garbage collection, so `b` can't just be a container pointing to `a`.

Why would a dictionary of 1d arrays take up less memory than those same arrays in an ndarray?

Comment: `getsizeof` is useless for this purpose

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj! What should I be using instead?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `sys.getsizeof`? What does it say?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I did read the documentation, which is why I deleted `a` and ran garbage collection. Per @mozway's answer below it does seem that even then the arrays within the dictionary remain stored elsewhere and the dictionary is still a container.

Comment: @morepenguins there's several fundamental misunderstandings at foot here. For starters, I was referring to this part of the documentation, which answers your question exactly: "Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to... See recursive sizeof recipe for an example of using getsizeof() recursively to find the size of containers and all their contents".

Comment: @morepenguins and of course the arrays still remain in the dictionary, using `del a` deletes *the variable `a`*, it is **not possible to delete objects in Python**, it is a memory managed language that doesn't expose any direct way to do that, objects are allocated on a privately managed heap. Also, if you are referring to `gc`, that is irrelevant here, `gc` controls the auxilliary garbage collector that is in charge of handling reference cycles, this wouldn't affect anything here. The main garbage collections strategy in CPython is reference counting

Comment: For arrays, `nbytes` is a good measure of the size.  Or take the product of the dimensions (how many elements) times bytes per element (typically 8).  That's assuming the array has its own memory.  If it's a `view` than the added memory use is negligible.  That's why you need to understand how arrays are stored, and what actions produce `view` versus `copy`.  `dict`, `list` and `object` dtype arrays store references, so  the total memory is basically the sum of the individual uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fundamental mistakes in your observation.

1. you cannot delete an object, only references. If you delete `a` you delete the pointer. When you delete all pointers then only the object *might* get deleted at some point by the garbage collector
2. `sys.getsizeof` only gives the size of the container. To get the total size you need to loop over the elements and sum.

Demonstration that the size is roughly the same:

```
b = {}
for ii in range(1000):
    b[f'{ii}']=a[:,ii].copy()
sum(sys.getsizeof(e) for e in b.values())
# 4096000
```

Comment: Thanks! So is `sys.getsizeof(b))` just measuring the size of the keys?

Comment: Check the doc for the details, but yes. The dictionary object itself, the pointers etc. but not the content.

Comment: @morepenguins Really, you'd need something like `sum(sys.getsizeof(k) + sys.getsizeof(v) for k,v in d.items())`, assuming the key and values themselves don't refer to any other objects, otherwise you have to recursively get *their* size too. [Here is an example, linked to in the docs](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) of how this could be done, note, in the general case you have to be careful to avoid infinite loops arising due to reference cycles

Comment: And actually here, you are dealling with an added complication that numpy arrays created by slicing another array, e.g. `a[:,ii]` **creates a view**, so no additional memory is allocated for the underlying buffer, only the Python-level object. Note, since here `.copy()` was used, this is avoided, but is a concern if you are dealling with numpy in general